# how to pick a lower brightness monitor

Tags: monitors, displays

on my monitor now I'm on 0% brightness and during the day it's ok for me, but at night is much too bright, and **I don't know at what specs to look at when buying a new monitor that will be able to get much lower brightness**.

---

I switched from a sony vaio laptop with TN screen to a MVA monitor (Benq EW2430)
and 0% brightness is ok for me during the day, but sometimes, evening/night I need it much lower brightness. I'm trying to pick a new monitor but I don't know how to choose one so that it would be able to provide a much lower brightness lower boundary.

It will also be nice if I could control the monitor brightness from windows 10 right side bar (that you open when clicking button next to the clock), like with laptops, in my current one I can control the brightness only by touching the monitor physical buttons.

**please note:** 
I can change the brightness in the video card settings but it's not the same as actually lowering monitor brightness, I would prefer to buy a new monitor

Comment: Brightness isn't the correct setting...You should usually be able to control the backlight. Did you try the Eco mode on your monitor? Menu -> Picture Advanced -> Picture Mode -> Eco

Comment: @NatsuKage Usually brightness corresponds to the monitor backlight (assuming you're using the native brightness control on the monitor.)

Comment: @JMY1000 Yes...depends on the monitor. Some have Brightness and Backlight like a TV, so brightness controls the black level. The Benq EW2430 just says brightness, so it's it's probably the backlight. Eco mode might have a lower setting available...or not.

Comment: on "Eco" brightness is on 35 and I can't control it, anyway, my question is how to pick a new monitor that would be able to provide a lower brightness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display brightness should be in the specs as [nits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candela_per_square_metre) or candelas per square metre (symbol: cd/m2). Each model offered you should have a specifications page or document on the Internet you can reference, if not printed in the device manual. Look for the lower number in the range of nits from lower to higher.

Alternatively, [polarizing computer display filters](https://www.google.com/search?q=computer%20screen%20polarizing%20filter) are inexpensive and easy to add to nearly any display.